# Valgrind doesn't show the sources of definitely lost memory

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

Valgrind detects memory that is definitely lost but doesn't show me the source (just question marks):

```
==9859== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 61 of 274
==9859==    at 0x4C244E8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==9859==    by 0x100F8FB9: ???
==9859==    by 0x3A6F: ???
==9859==    by 0x1F: ???
==9859==    by 0x12C24F07: ???
==9859==    by 0x87: ???
```

Why are the sources not shown (not even the start in the *main()* function)? What should I do? Where do I need to look to determine the problem or the sources of the leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most often source of question marks instead of function names(at least in my practice) is the lack of the debugging info. If you're using gcc, try compiling and linking with -g option.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use debug versions of all my dependencies (even the implicit ones).